# What is use of "spark.streaming.blockInterval" in Spark Streaming DirectAPI

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I want to understand, What role `"spark.streaming.blockInterval"` plays in Spark Streaming DirectAPI, as per my understanding `"spark.streaming.blockInterval"` is used for calculating partitions i.e. `#partitions = (receivers x* batchInterval) /blockInterval`, but in DirectAPI spark streaming partitions is equal to no. of kafka partitions.

How `"spark.streaming.blockInterval"` is used in DirectAPI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spark.streaming.blockInterval :

> Interval at which data received by Spark Streaming **receivers** is chunked into blocks of data before storing them in Spark.

And KafkaUtils.createDirectStream() do not use receiver.

> With directStream, Spark Streaming will create as many RDD partitions
>   as there are Kafka partitions to consume

Comment: That means block interval configuration is of no use in DirectAPI right ?

Comment: @nilesh1212  yes,http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers